# Does the MRTK include animated hand visualizers with grab functionality for use with their VR headsets?

Tags: mrtk

Looking at the sample scenes, it seems like the MRTK uses a pointer system instead of actually giving you virtual hands that can be manipulated by pressing buttons or triggers on the controllers, and allowing you to grab objects.

Is there a built-in way to use hands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently not a set of virtual hands build into MRTK for VR, however it would be possible to rig up a custom visual for a controller that looks like hands, and animate the hands based on things like which buttons / triggers are pressed on the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Oculus provide hand models which are rigged in their SDK, which you can appropriate for use in the MRTK as shown in the video below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3e2lwqVPyc&list=PLCK8aOPy3e4JhG06GRdlJkmNXoITEewxV&index=4

You'd just need to do a little more work to get the hand rigging hooked up to the MRTK hands.